# option[Any] pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've written the following code for finding the value corresponding to a key and returning it as Double.

```
def getDouble (key: String, map: HashMap[String, _]) : Double = {
    if (map contains key) {
        val o = map get key
        o match {
          case Some(i: Int) => return i.asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble;
          case Some(d: Double) => return d.asInstanceOf[Double];
          case Some(s: String) 
              => return  augmentString(s.asInstanceOf[String]).toDouble;
          case Some(int) => return o.asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble;
          case Some(double) => return o.asInstanceOf[Double].toDouble;

          case _ => return -1234567.00;
        }
    }
    else {
      return -1234567.00
    }
}
```

What is the difference between `case Some(int)` and `case Some(i: Int)`?

Do I need to use both `case Some(int)` and `case Some(i: Int)` for checking type int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Some(int)` matches any `Some`, and declares a variable named `int` of type `Any` from the contents of the `Option`. `int` is just an identifier here, not a type. So for example `Some("String")` would be matched by it, and would throw an exception when you tried to return it as an `Int`.

`Some(i:Int)` only matches if `o` is an int, and declares a variable named `i` of type `Int`. This means you don't need the `asInstanceOf` in this case, because it's already an `Int`.

What you want for your code is this:

```
def getDouble (key: String, map: HashMap[String, _]) : Double = {
  val o = map get key
  o match {
    case Some(i: Int) => i.toDouble;
    case Some(d: Double) => d;
    case Some(s: String) => augmentString(s).toDouble;
    case _ => -1234567.00;
  }
}
```

This removes

1. The `asInstanceOf`s. Correctly matching on type makes them unnecessary, and they're generally considered bad practice.
2. The `map contains key` check, because if it's not contained, it will return `None`, which is caught by `case _ =>`.
3. The unnecessary `return`s. Since the `match` is the final thing in the function, its own value will automatically be the return value.